# How to display a DataGrid property with combo box/drop down list that varies according to input of another text box property

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu, datagrid, itemsource

I have a DataGrid which is bind to a list like below that has various properties. I have 2 requirements that i am struggling with.

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VariedObjectList}" 
AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn" x:Name="dataGridView"
                          SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CanUserAddRows="true"  CanUserDeleteRows="true />
```

1. For a specific value in the text box property1, the list of items displayed in property2 should dynamically change. So, for ex, here
   if 'Value' has value say 2, then the 'ValueRange' should display a dropdown with items say "2-5" and "5.81-6.6" as list items and if Value is 8 then list changes to => 7.9-8.8 ; 8.81-11.2 and so on like in below image.

How can i achieve this ?  I would like to keep the binding to the entire collection itself as in above xaml.

[image]

```
 public class VariedObjectList
{
    public Modes ModeType { get; set; }
    public int Value{ get; set; }
    public <dataType??> ValueRange { get; set; } // not sure what should be the type for ValueRange

}
public enum Mode
    {
        ModeSlow = 0,
        ModeFast = 1,
        ModeNeutral = 2,
        ModeNone = 3
    }
```

2. If my 'ModeType' property is 'ModeSlow' or 'ModeFast' then 'ValueRange' will need to be a dropDownlist. If ModeType is "ModeNeutral" then ValueRange has to accept a textBox. How do i achieve this?

---

I modified the code as suggested by Keith and although most of my changes are working, i have problem in the below areas

(i)i could not get to have the combo box editable working. It takes value when i type in but once my focus leaves the field, the text disappears and binding never happens with 'SelectedValueRange' for text entered. But when there is a list and if i select any value from list, that gets binded to 'SelectedValueRange' but not for text input.

(ii)ModeType being enum, when new row is entered by default i want it to display 'ModeSlow' but its empty. Also, if I update one row, all the previous rows are also updated with the latest value.its behaviour is wierd but i know i am missing something.

```
public class VariedObjectList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Mode ModeType { get; set; } = Mode.ModeSlow;
    private int val;
    public int Value {
            get { return val; }
            set
            {
                val = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                SetValueRangeList();
            }
        }
    public List<strings> ValueRange { get; set; } 
    public string SelectedValueRange {get; set;}

}
```

below is updated xaml

I am setting the ObjectDataProvider for the Enum

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumProvider" MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:Modes"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources >
```

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView" Grid.Row="0" DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridGotFocus" ItemsSource="{Binding VariedObjectList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                               CanUserDeleteRows="true"  SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header=" ModeType " >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumProvider}}"
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path= ModeType 
, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="ValueRange" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValueRange, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ValueRange }" /> 
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValueRange, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Can someone please point out what am i missing with sample code? Thanks.

Comment: Is this possible? I see so many views but no response. Please, let me know if more information would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the `VariedObjectList` class:

- Since `ValueRange` is going to be changing nd you want the UI to update with it, `VariedObjectList` is going to have to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged).
- The type for `ValueRange` can be any generic collection of `int`. I would recoomend declaring the property as `IList<int>`, because it gives you lots of room to use different collections if you need to.
- In `ModeType.set`, along with raising `PropertyChanged`, you'll need to create or retrieve the list of values you want to display for that `Mode` and then assign that list to `ValueRange`.

Now for the `DataGrid`:

If you want to change the behavior of the `ValueRange` column depending on `ModeType`, you're going to have to give up `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` Instead, you'll explicitly define the columns between `<DataGrid.Columns>` tags.

I would recommend `DataGridTemplateColumn` for the `ValueRange` column. The `CellEditingTemplate` would contain a `ComboBox` with `ItemsSource={Binding ValueRange}`. You can apply a `Style` to the `ComboBox` that changes [`IsEditable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable) depending on the value of `ModeType`. This will let you set the ability of the user to enter text which doesn't match any items in the list.

For the editable `ComboBox`, you will have to use the `Text` property. `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` only work when selecting an item from the drop down, not when entering custom text.

Comment: thanks Keith. I am going to try your recommendation and will come back with any questions for clarifications.

Comment: I have edited with my modified code. I am stuck with 2 problem areas. Can you please take a look and help me.?

Comment: Should I post this as separate question?

Comment: @jamilia I updated my answer with something that should address the editable `ComboBox`, but I'm not sure about the rest. You might be better off starting a second question for these new problems.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I will post rest of them separately. One quick question, with the above setup, is it possible to edit only if the list is NullorEmpty ? I don't want the user to type in any input if there is a list with values which they should only be able to select. They should be able to edit only if the list is null or empty. is this possible?

Comment: @jamilia You could add a `Style` to the `ComboBox` with a `DataTrigger` to change the `IsEditable` property based on the list value.

Comment: I looked at applying Style to Combo box with isEditable. With this will i be able to Validate my text box? If user enters input and if it has errors, it needs to notifyonerror. This validation should be only for text box entry not for combo box.

Comment: @jamilia Yes, you should be able to style it so that the validation only applies to the editable `ComboBox`, but not to the drop-down-only one.